# How to develop a custom keyboard in Brightscript?

Tags: keyboard, roku, brightscript

I'm trying to create a custom keyboard in Brightscript. I found Youtube and Netflix are using their own keyboard layout.And the Roku's keyboard is kinda different. Not clean like Youtube and Netflix. From Roku's Brightscript [documentation](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Keyboard), I found this

> The default appearance of a Keyboard node is very transparent,
>   allowing the keyboard to pick up most of its color from what is
>   rendered underneath it. The appearance can be customized by changing
>   the keyboardBitmapUri and other fields.

**keyboardBitmapUri** - *Specifies the URI of an image file to be loaded to replace the default keyboard image drawn underneath the key label and icons.Note that this image must be carefully designed so that the key positions match the default image. Template images for SD, HD and FHD resolutions are provided below.*

Is there any sample code to do like these keyboard layouts?

**Netflix Keyboard**

[image]

**Youtube Keyboard**

[image]

I was using a [keyboard dialog](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/KeyboardDialog) with the following code

```
sub showdialog()
     screen = CreateObject("roKeyboardScreen")
     port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
     screen.SetMessagePort(port)
     screen.SetTitle("Search Screen")
     screen.SetText("default")
     screen.SetDisplayText("enter text to search")
     screen.SetMaxLength(8)
     screen.AddButton(1, "finished")
     screen.AddButton(2, "back")
     screen.Show()

     while true
         msg = wait(0, screen.GetMessagePort())
         print "message received"
         if type(msg) = "roKeyboardScreenEvent"
             if msg.isScreenClosed()
                 return
             else if msg.isButtonPressed() then
                 print "Evt:"; msg.GetMessage ();" idx:"; msg.GetIndex()
                 if msg.GetIndex() = 1
                     searchText = screen.GetText()
                     print "search text: "; searchText
                     return
                 endif
             endif
         endif
     end while
    end sub
```

If you have any suggestion, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Netflix and YouTube almost certainly are not using `roKeyboardScreen`. If you want to customize `roKeyboardScreen`, use the templates given - with the layout as provided.

Comment: Where are those templates? They are giving default keyboard templates. Right?

Comment: What do you mean "where"? You ask and then say "they are giving" them. Are you confused because of the word "default"? Download the templates, edit them to your liking and then link to the results in `keyboardBitmapUri`

Answer (score 1):

You can always create your own custom keyboard, take a look at this example that I have developed. It's a custom keypad (for numeric entry) the code is available under MIT license at:

https://github.com/lvcabral/RokuNumericKeypad